# Running Django tests.py on method that updates object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing

I'm using Django to try to run a test, and something's going wrong. Here's a minimal example:

models.py:

```
class Warrior(models.Model):
    is_alive = models.BooleanField("Is Alive?", default=True)
    def kill(self):
        self.alive = False
        self.save()
```

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Warrior

class WarriorModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_kill(self):
        """kill() makes .alive False."""
        warrior = Warrior.objects.create()
        warrior.kill()
        self.assertIs(warrior.is_alive, False)
```

Any advice on this? I'm starting to think this little warrior chap is immortal. Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `kill()` function sets `alive` to `False`, then you should assert the value of `alive` rather than `is_alive`, isn't it?

You could print out the values to debug this.